# How to Pass multiple file values in XMLhttp Post request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using FileReader() to get the file values. How can I make Http post request to post multiple file values as input.

```
var fi = document.getElementById('myFile');

    if (fi.files.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < fi.files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.readAsDataURL(fi.files[i]);
            var f = fi.files[i];
                    file_input = reader.result.split("base64,").pop();
                    var attachment_type = fi.files[i].type;
                    var filename = fi.files[i].name;
                }
            }
```

HTTP request

```
var data = JSON.stringify(
        {
            "firstname": First,
            "lastname": Last,
            "file": [
                {
                    "input_file": file_input,
                    "attachment_type": attachment_type,
                    "file_name": filename
                }     ]   }  );

    var url = "";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true)
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');  
    xhr.send(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the arrays of input_file, attachemnt_type, file_name and process the files using array indices.

Comment: can you explain me in more detail

Comment: The JSON will contain value as array.  Make arrays as: 
var file_input = []; 
var attachment_type = [];
var file_name = [];

Now, append the array in each iteration of your 'for loop'.

JSON will remain same.